# nl2br in php code does not generate new line

Tags: php, newline

I'm trying to print two 3-digit random numbers one below the other. I've tried a bunch of functions but it does not seem to output a new line and the second random number.

Code is as follows:

```
<?php
echo "<h1><center>Random php</center></h1>"; 
echo rand(100,990);
echo nl2br(“\n”,false);
echo rand(100,990);
?>
```

The output is as follows on the browser.

> Random php
>
> 698 Fatal error: Undefined constant 'â€œ\nâ€' in /Volumes/Macintosh
>   Media/code/random/main.php on line 4

Comment: nl2br takes a string of what should be on a new line. You are actually passing it a newline only ... Why not just echo a `<br>`?

Comment: You forgot the `<marquee>` tag for the header..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your quotation marks. Use the proper ones (ASCII quotes). Apart from that just use `<br />`

Answer (score 3):

You are using curly quotes instead of the ASCII double-quote character in `nl2br`:

```
echo nl2br(“\n”,false);
```

instead of

```
echo nl2br("\n",false);
```

PHP does not know what to do with the curly quotes and is trying to parse the entire thing (`“\n”`) as the name of a constant (which of course does not exist).

In any case, it is much simpler to do as Harshit Shrivastava suggests and print a `<br>` rather than use the `nl2br()` function here.

Comment: @Maverick447 - This is the right answer. As using `<br>` is merely a suggestion, this actually addresses your concern why your `\n` was not making a `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

`nl2br` insert line breaks where newlines (\n) or carriage (\r) occur in the string:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");
?>
```

This will output as folows

> One line.
>   Another line.

For your code to work, use `<br>`

```
<?php
echo "<h1><center>Random php</center></h1>"; 
echo rand(100,990);
echo "<br>";
echo rand(100,990);
?>
```

Check the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for more on this

Comment: nl2br is used to convert newlines and carriage returns,  `\n` and `\r` respectively, not just `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<BR>`.

```
<?php
echo "<h1><center>Random php</center></h1>"; 
echo rand(100,990);
echo "<BR>";
echo rand(100,990);
?>
```

nl2br is use to convert `\n` to `<BR>`

Comment: nl2br is used to convert newlines and carriage returns `\n` and `\r` respectively, not just `\n`. This may be just my preference, but there is no need for `<BR>` to be in all caps, `<br>` will suffice.